# Macro no Outlook 2010 OnTime()

Tags: vba, microsoft

Eae galera, preciso fazer uma macro no MS Outlook que só execute em determinada faixa de horário, existe alguma função que me ajude com isso??

Vi que no Excel existe a OnTime(), mas parece que no Outlook não existe a mesma.

Comment: Não conheço as nuances do VBA no Outlook. Mas, no mínimo deve ser possível usar o timer nativo do Windows. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx (o texto é voltado pro Excel, mas a última parte sobre Windows Timers, deve lhe ser útil).

Answer (score 1):

Gente encontrei a solução do meu problema, talvez eu não tenha sido muito claro na pergunta, bom segue o que fiz

```
Sub teste(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim minTime, maxTime As String
minTime = "18:00:00"
maxTime = "05:00:00"


If Time() > minTime Or Time() < maxTime Then
    MsgBox ("Funcionou")
End If
End Sub
```

Muito obrigado